# Hardwood worth fixing?

Tags: hardwood

Pulled up the carpets and found this section of hardwood in one room that looks like it’s been water damaged and is pretty warped. I was thinking of refinishing the floor but I think these would need replacing. Wondering if it’s worth the time/cost or if I should just put down laminate over top instead? I’m confident with diying the restraining but unsure about how to deal with this. Any opinions would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can't be refinished. It needs to be replaced. The only way to reuse this wood is to take it out, re-mill it, and reinstall it. And even if you had the equipment to do it, it would not be worth the effort. It can only imagine it being worth if it was some super rare hardwood, or the wood had some historical significance that added value to the house.

If it's worth it for you to replace it, depends on the rest of the house. If the rest of the house has beautiful hardwood floors, it's probably worth replacing the wood.

If the rest of the house is a mix of carpet, old wood, etc., then just cover it with vinyl.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually really cool. I'd sand it, but not enough to take the patina off. Finish nail gun down w/e offensive boards you can. Sand down any tripping hazards, get half way through the finish throughout, and then quit. Shabby chic is all the rage don't you know.